# Paypal Not Working After Magento Upgrade from 1.6 to 1.9

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I have upgraded Magneto from 1.6 to 1.9 and after this Paypal is not working.

In checkout page after selecting Paypal as payment option, it goes to blank page (www.site.com/paypal/express/start/) and no error is showing on that page.

I have checked logs and enabled errors but nothing happened.

Comment: Try to replace your theme files with these files  and check   app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/express/shortcut.phtml
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/express/review.phtml  files with

Comment: @Muk I don't have any Paypal folder in my custom theme. So i created and uploaded these two files but no luck. Thanks.

Comment: Check the base/default/template/paypal/ folder of your installation with Magento 1.9 , if files are missing move files there.

Comment: @Muk, All files are present there.